# Why does casting a null to a primitive(ie: int) in .net 2.0 throw a null ref exception and not a invalid cast exception?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, casting

I was going through some code and came across a scenario where my combobox has not been initialized yet.  This is in .NET 2.0 and in the following code, this.cbRegion.SelectedValue is null.

```
int id = (int)this.cbRegion.SelectedValue;
```

This code threw a null reference exception instead of an invalid cast exception.  I was wondering if anyone knew why it would throw a null reference exception instead of a invalid cast?

Comment: Why does it matter which exception it throws? Just curiosity or is it causing some other problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to do with [Boxing](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive100.html) and unboxing.  It is trying to pull an int out of the box (unbox), but the object is null, so you get a null reference exception before it ever gets the change to cast.

Comment: Quote: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b95fkada(v=vs.80).aspx"
 Attempting to unbox null or a reference to an incompatible value type will result in an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov It's great that the documentation says that but every actual implementation throws NullReferenceException when you actually attempt it.

Comment: @JoshuaPech might be just outdated,  yes

Answer (score 8):

If you compile

```
object o = null;
int a = (int)o;
```

and look at the MSIL code, you'll see something like

```
ldnull
...
unbox.any int32
```

Now the behavior for unbox.any is specified as follows:

> InvalidCastException is thrown if obj
>   is not a boxed type.
>
> NullReferenceException is thrown if
>   obj is a null reference.

This is what you see in your code.

Comment: COOL, I never even thought about decompiling it and checking out the instructions used.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's attempting to read the object before it casts it. Hence you're getting the null exception instead of a cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is on the Selected Value which is null. It's never even getting to the cast.

Comment: This is not quite correct. It throws while trying to cast or, specifically, to unbox a null reference.