# A null object cast to int causes NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, nullreferenceexception

I have the following generic code:

```
public V put(K key, V value){
        Object o = doOp(ClusterOperation.CONCURRENT_MAP_PUT, key, value);           
        return (V)o;
}
```

The thing is, the Object o can be null. When I work with objects like String it is ok to return null cast to String. But when V represents int, then null cast to int throws NullReferenceException.

Is there any solution that is generic enough and handles int's?

Thanks

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361258/why-does-casting-a-null-to-a-primitiveie-int-in-net-2-0-throw-a-null-ref-exc

Comment: I sow that question, before posting. It wasn't enough for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword:

```
if(o == null)
  return default(V);

return (V)o;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `int?` (i.e. a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) `int`) instead of `int`.

Comment: I accepted the Oded's answer. But your hint enabled me to understand that int is different from int? . +1 for that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

int cannot be null as long as it's not an nullable int. If your int can be null it also feels like it's the correct solution to use nullable anyways.